# MATLAB - Extracting red color from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, computer-vision, extract

Why does the following code extract components similar to the red channel of an image?

```
diff_im = imsubtract(data(:,:,1), rgb2gray(data));
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. A question starting by "Why", isn't really helpful. What the problem, this code works fine.

Comment: It works, yes. But I don't know why. If I subtract the grayscale image from the red component of the image, why does it extract the red color for me?
Is that a bit clearer? :/

Comment: The red channel is extracted in one of your arguments: data(:,:,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only *looks* like the red channel. Your code is extracting the luminance (`rgb2gray(data)`) from the red channel (`data(:,:,1)`), which would give a kind of normalized red channel except that negative values are truncated to zero.

If `data` is an unsigned integer (probably `uint8`), the subtraction cannot give negative values, so any pixel without a prominent red component will be set to zero. You can see a map of these pixels by subtracting in a signed data type and comparing the result:

```
redMap = diff_im > (double(data(:,:,1))-double(rgb2gray(data)))
```